# Can't use System.IO.File.Copy() to copy file to Volume Id

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a C# WinForm app using .Net Framework 4.5.2. I'm grabbing a list of Volume Ids and so I can copy a file to the root folder.

```
  ManagementObjectSearcher ms = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Volume");    
foreach(ManagementObject mo in ms.Get())   
{
    var guid = mo["DeviceID"].ToString();
}
```

Then I grab the Volume Id and call System.IO.File.Copy() to copy

```
System.IO.File.Copy( "a.pdf", System.IO.Path.Combine( @"\\?\Volume{c06fa891-c5a9-11e7-9bc6-f01faf0be092}\", "a.pdf" ) );
```

But get "Illegal characters in path."

```
      at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String fullPath, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)
   at ThumbDrives.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in Form1.cs:line 46
```

I know it's not a permission issue and I can use "copy" in command prompt to copy the file to Volume Id. Is it possible to copy files using .Net Framework to copy files using Volume Id instead of the drive letter?

Thanks

Comment: What framework version? Looking at the reference source, you may get away with it if you disable `UseLegacyPathHandling`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/appcontextswitchoverrides-element  and here's where the check is https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/permissions/fileiopermission.cs,b2a474881a0dd2f5

Comment: The framework version is the in the first sentence.

Comment: I failed at reading and recognized it after I could update the comment. You may have to bump it up.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I added <runtime>  
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling=false" />    
</runtime>

Comment: Wonderful. I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Microsoft's Reference Source for [EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/permissions/fileiopermission.cs,b2a474881a0dd2f5), you should be able to get this to work if you disable `UseLegacyPathHandling` as noted by [AppContextSwitchOverrides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/appcontextswitchoverrides-element) page.

```
internal static void EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(string fullPath)
{
    //...
    if (AppContextSwitches.UseLegacyPathHandling || !PathInternal.IsDevice(fullPath))
    {
        if (PathInternal.HasWildCardCharacters(fullPath))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_InvalidPathChars"));
        }

        //...
    }
}
```

Example Config:

```
<configuration>  
    <runtime>
        <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling=false" /> 
    </runtime> 
</configuration>
```